# Batch file: compare files?

Tags: file, batch-file, compare

I have a batch file for checking files in a map.

My situation:

I have for example Map A on Directory A.
On Directory B I have also Map A. But on Directory B are people working in those files, so there is a change that files can be delete or missing.
Now I want compare those 2 maps for missing files, that maybe delete or is missing.

So comparing must be like this:

Directory A with Map A :compare-> Directory B with Map A

Result must be: No changes or missing files!

Can you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: What is a `map` here? What OS are you using?

Comment: Map or Folder. OS is Windows 7

Comment: Compare Folder 1 on location A -> Folder 1 on location B.
So the same folder with the same files but on another location. Making a batch for searching different file names.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly shared the remote directory on your network, and have configured the relevant NetBIOS, TCP/IP settings, and are on the same Subnet Mask etc. Then something like this should work:

```
@echo off
net use x: "\\COMPUTER-NAME\PATH-TO-SHARED-SUBDIRECTORY" 

del /q "missing.txt" 2>nul

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d-h x:') do (
if not exist "%userprofile%\DIRECTORY-PATH\%%i" echo %%i
)>>missing.txt
pause
```

I may have it the wrong way around, otherwise it would be:

```
@echo off
net use x: "\\COMPUTER-NAME\PATH-TO-SHARED-SUBDIRECTORY"

del /q "missing.txt" 2>nul

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /a:-d-h "%userprofile%\SUBDIRECTORY-PATH\"') do (
if not exist "x:\%%i" echo %%i
)>>missing.txt
pause
```

Either way the command you'd be interested in, among others, is [`net use`](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
xcopy /L /d "directory a\*" "directory b\*"
```

will show the files that are in directory A but missing or changed in directory B.